# What does multi-periodicity mean in stellar pulsations?

Tags: astrophysics, terminology, fourier-transform, stars, oscillators

How can there exist multi-periodicity in stellar pulsations?
http://www.kitp.ucsb.edu/sites/default/files/kitp/preprints/moskalik2.pdf
How can one visualize a multi-periodic pulsation or oscillation?

Comment: It would be best if you quote the relevant parts of the linked pdf in the question.

Comment: From the Abstract "different forms of multi-periodicity observed in Cepheids and RR Lyrae stars, including Blazhko effect and various types of radial and nonradial multi-mode oscillations"

Comment: I think the pulsation amplitude varies with time in a cycle with two periods,one the fundamental period and other the modulation period.This is called multi-periodicity.

Answer (score 2):

In stellar pulsations, multi-periodicity literally just means that there is more than one period present. In the cases of the classical pulsators (usually Cepheids and RR Lyraes), this is noteworthy purely because some stars oscillate at multiple frequencies and some don't.  Typically we see the fundamental radial mode, and sometimes harmonics thereof.

How to visualize it? It's no different from oscillation of simpler systems. (We compute oscillation frequencies assuming linearized perturbations.) Think for a moment about a violin string. When you pluck it or bow it, it vibrates with a particular set of frequencies, determined mainly by the length of the string. There's a fundamental mode, which is the lowest possible frequency, but also many harmonics: multiples of this principal frequency. When you play a violin, you're actually exciting many of these modes at the same time, which gives the violin it's sound.  Consider how a flute sounds different even when playing the same note, because the pattern of amplitudes over these many frequencies looks different.

To build up a multi-periodic string, you just add the oscillations to each other, since it's a linear problem. Similarly, for a star, we can express the oscillations as functions over it's volume, and the oscillations of a multi-periodic star are just the sum of the multiple oscillations.